# What's a good way to publish database definition changes from a development copy to a production copy of a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

How can I track changes to a development database and apply those changes to a production database (SQL Server 2008)?

I keep a local copy of a database on my development server, and as I'm adding new features, I may add new tables or change field and table names in the database.  What's a good way to track such changes and then apply them to the main database?

Is there some way to do a "diff"-like operation between two databases and merge definition changes?

I considered merge-replication, but I'm not sure how well than handles schema changes.  For example, here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx it mentions that I basically cannot use SSMS to make definition changes, because it drops and recreates tables, which is not allowed for published objects.

A smart piece of software could compare column counts, types, positions, and apply other fuzzy matching/logical deduction methods to figure out that a table was renamed or a new table was added or a column name changed, after which it could present the differences to the user for confirmation and automatic application.

Does anything like what I've described above exist, or am I stuck remembering to save DDL statements in SSMS and running them manually in the production database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need a migration tool like (for example) [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator), which helps you track database changes in source code.

[Here is a tutorial](http://lostechies.com/seanchambers/2011/04/02/fluentmigrator-getting-started/) from the original author of Fluent Migrator, explaining what Fluent Migrator is, why you might need it and how it works.

Another alternative would be what you already mentioned:

> A smart piece of software could compare column counts, types,
>   positions, and apply other fuzzy matching/logical deduction methods to
>   figure out that a table was renamed or a new table was added or a
>   column name changed, after which it could present the differences to
>   the user for confirmation and automatic application.

I never tried it myself, but I've seen lots of recommendations for [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) (which apparently does exactly what you asked for) here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: SQL Compare could save time in some scenarios, but it can't compare objects with different names or even map one name to another for comparison, as discussed here: http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?p=31775#31775. It also mentions "SQL Data Compare" http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/ -- a different product by the same company -- can perform a data comparison to find a matching table, but I'm not sure how useful or efficient that method would be.  FluentMigrator is more of a deployment tool using definition statements, which is not what I need.

Comment: I think a custom implementation with some simple logic could do a better job than SQL Compare as far as simply "identifying" differences, and could be developed in a week or two.  The complicated part, where SQL Compare excels, would be in generating the SQL statements, identifying dependencies to determining the proper statement issuance order, and actually applying the changes.